# localStorage differentiate between non-existent key and null value

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

In some cases, I need to store information in the localStorage that some 'objects' are null. But it does not support that.

```
localStorage.setItem('tt', null);
const tt = localStorage.getItem('tt');
console.log(tt.length);
console.log(`tt is ${tt == null ? '' : 'NOT '}null`);
```

this code puts to console:

```
4
tt is NOT null
```

Why?

I can adjust my logic and avoid saving null objects in the storage, but in some circumstances, you want to differentiate data "object's value is unknown" vs "object's value is null".

Should I just use another variable for that?

Comment: I think you dont need to save the null value. normally if you dont have the item on the localStorage, you will get an undefined/null

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) the return value of `getItem` is a DomString

`A DOMString containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned.`

If you want to say null, you'll need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

```
localStorage.setItem('tt', JSON.stringify(null));
const tt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tt'));

console.log(`tt is ${tt == null ? '' : 'NOT '}null`);
```

Answer (score 1):

based on the documentation the setItem receives the DOMString which converts null to string "null". That's why when you save null you get length 4.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString

> Certain Web APIs accepting a DOMString have an additional legacy behavior, where passing null stringifies to the empty string instead of the usual "null".

If you want set null I would use removeItem("tt") to get null value.

Answer (score -1):

`localStorage` can only store string key/value pairs; thus `null` will be converted to string form (`'null'`) when you set the item in `localStorage`.

Using strict type checking when comparing to `null` will solve the problem:

```js
localStorage.setItem('tt', null);
const tt = localStorage.getItem('tt');
console.log(`tt is ${tt === null ? '' : 'NOT '}null`);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check whether the key exists:

```js
console.log(`tt is ${'tt' in localStorage ? 'NOT' : ''} null`);
```